# C++ Access private static member from public static method?

Tags: c++, class, static, private, member

Let's say I have a .hpp file containing a simple class with a public static method and a private static member/variable.
This is an example class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static int DoSomethingWithTheVar()
    {
        TheVar = 10;
        return TheVar;
    }
private:
    static int TheVar;
}
```

And when I call:

```
int Result = MyClass::DoSomethingWithTheVar();
```

I would expect that "Result" is equal to 10;

Instead I get (at line 10):

```
undefined reference to `MyClass::TheVar'
```

Line 10 is "TheVar = 10;" from the method.

My question is if its possible to access a private static member (TheVar) from a static method (DoSomethingWithTheVar)?

Comment: it's got nothing to do with access or privateness. It has to do with absense of a definition of `TheVar`. It's only been declared.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The response to your question is yes ! You just missed to define the static member `TheVar` :

```
int MyClass::TheVar = 0;
```

In a cpp file.

It is to respect the [One definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Example :

```
// Myclass.h
class MyClass
{
public:
    static int DoSomethingWithTheVar()
    {
        TheVar = 10;
        return TheVar;
    }
private:
    static int TheVar;
};

// Myclass.cpp
#include "Myclass.h"

int MyClass::TheVar = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I tried that however I always get an error saying that I cannot access TheVar because it was private. The reason was that I always forgot to put the type (int) at the beginning so the compiler probably thought I want to access that private member. (Epic mistake sorry to bother)

Comment: @SanduLiviuCatalin So your problem is solved now ? [An example](http://ideone.com/V58sWe) of this working :)

Comment: Yes. I'm waiting to become 15 minutes old so that I can mark it as solved.