# How to extern global smart pointers that are assigned within SetUpTestSuite?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have a couple global pointers defined in a `UtTestBase.hpp` which are to be used by the files that include it (e.g: `UtTest1.cpp`).

`SetUpTestSuite()` is `static` and thus performs a shared set up for all the tests. I view it as preconfiguration. Doing the way I have would complain about multiple definitions of the globals however using `extern` for each doesn't work either.
Using `extern` errors out

```
namespace TEST
{
extern std::weak_ptr<int> weakPtr;
extern std::shared_ptr<int> sharedInt;
// ...
}

// errors
undefined reference to `weakPtr' in line "weakPtr = sharedInt;"
undefined reference to `sharedInt' in line "sharedInt = std::make_shared<int>();"
```

From what I have seen the usage of `extern` involves declaring the variables in a header and defining in a respective source file that uses it

What's the way around? `static inline` is other option but does it make sense for each file to have a separate instance of a global given they are assigned in `SetUpTestSuite()`?

**UtTestBase.hpp**

```
namespace TEST
{
std::weak_ptr<int> weakPtr;
std::shared_ptr<int> sharedInt;

struct UtTestBase
{
  static void SetUpTestSuite()
  {
     sharedInt = std::make_shared<int>();
     weakPtr = sharedInt;
  }
  // .. some common methods
};
}
```

**UtTestBase.cpp**

```
#include "UtTestBase.hpp"

namespace TEST
{
TEST_F(UtTestBase, Test1)
{
  // ...
}
}
```

**UtTest1.cpp**

```
#include "UtTestBase.hpp"

namespace TEST
{
struct UtTest1 : public UtTestBase
{
  void SetUp() override
  {
    // do init for a local test
  }
  // should have sharedInt and weakPtr assigned
};
}
```

Comment: Since you derive from UTTestBase, why not make them static members of the UTTestBase class?

Comment: I'd ideally make them member variables and have child classes access them but it's just `SetUpTestSuite()` is static

Comment: Yes but static methods can access static members. [C++ Access private static member from public static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433752/c-access-private-static-member-from-public-static-method)

Comment: True. making them `static` makes sense ... more than `static inline` which would mean each file would have its own instance, yes?

Comment: Just make them static, you need to initialize them in one of the cpp files though.

Comment: `weakPtr` is declared in namespace `TEST` while `extern` declares `weakPtr` in global namespace.

Comment: @PepijnKramer so I'd have to what's done in `SetUpTestSuite()` in one of the source files that's including it?

Comment: You can also use something called a meyer's singleton. Which is threadsafe (since C++11) and will initialize your variable on first use.  `int get_shared_int() { static int value{1}; return value;` or for a class  `const some_class& get_shared_class() { static const some_class object; return object; }`. I've used this too, though in general I try to stay away from globals/singletons.

Comment: What version of google test is this? Fixture classes should inherit `::testing::Test`.

Comment: @debido i am using `using namespace testing;` (not shown here)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the compile error with `extern` is that this only *references* the global variable. One of the translation units (exactly one!) has to *define* it, too. So, in the header, you need it declared with `extern`, and in one(!) of the cpp files, it additionally needs to be defined without `extern`.

If you don't define the variable anywhere (and only reference it with `extern`), the linker will complain that the variable doesn't exist - that's the error messages you're getting.

Here's a simple example with an int.

Header:

```
//Declare that the variable exists, don't actually create it
extern int g_whatever;
```

CPP file 1:

```
#include "Header"

//Create (define) the variable
int g_whatever;
```

CPP file 2, 3, ...:

```
#include "Header"

//Use g_whatever, *without* defining it again
```

This is independent of where you actually initialize the global variable. You could put the definition into UtTestBase.cpp, for example.

For a more in-depth explanation, see: [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind providing a solution based on my code though? defining it one cpp file now doesn't error out but fails with `exit code 11` when I run the test

Comment: If the linker error is gone, you're using `extern` correctly and are now running into a different, unrelated problem. GMock exit code 11 apparently means that your program segfaulted. Attach a debugger and check what happens.

Comment: I mean the problem wasn't only about using `extern` but more about using `extern` to solve the problem at hand given it's a test mock environment. `SetUpTestSuite` assigns the globals and that needs to happen before other files access the globals. Accessing the globals elsewhere *before* would certainly segfault. Do you see the problem here?

Comment: As far as I understood your question, you wanted a way to share these variables between cpp files - which you now can. If you now want to know how to make GMock call a function before executing tests, you can open a separate question, since it's completely independent of sharing variables. In general, you should only ask one question in a StackOverflow question. If you have multiple questions, create multiple questions.

Comment: created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75138102/how-to-share-globals-across-files-that-are-assigned-in-setuptestsuite

Comment: I am sorry. The question I opened has been closed so I expect your answer to be changed since it doesn't solve the problem...